# Combine text from multiple lines to form each row of a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, text-parsing

I'm trying to clean up the output  of

```
cscript 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs' /dstatus
```

I want to display only the license and the last 5 chars of the key such as

> Office16HomeBusinessR_Retail3 edition , 7H67X

I've got pieces of it, but can't quite bring it together.

```
$comp = "Computername"
$OfficLice = "C:\share\OfficLice.csv"
$localtemp = "C:\share\OfficLiceTemp.csv"

cscript 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs' /dstatus $comp | add-content $localtemp

$lic = get-content $localtemp | where {$_ -like "LICENSE NAME*"}
$key = get-content $localtemp | where {$_ -like "Last 5*"} 
$key = foreach ($item in $key){
    ($item -split ' ')[7]} 


foreach ($item in $lic){
     ($item -split ' ')[4] | add-content -Path  $OfficLice.("License Name")

}

foreach ($item in $key){
    $item | add-content -Path $OfficLice.Key
}
```

Here's a copy of what I'm trying to clean up

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

---Processing--------------------------
---------------------------------------
PRODUCT ID: 00333-59056-17787-AA631
SKU ID: 522f8458-7d49-42ff-a93b-670f6b6176ae
LICENSE NAME: Office 16, Office16HomeBusinessR_Retail3 edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 16, RETAIL channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---LICENSED--- 
Last 5 characters of installed product key: 7H67X
---------------------------------------
PRODUCT ID: 00340-00000-00000-AA482
SKU ID: 971cd368-f2e1-49c1-aedd-330909ce18b6
LICENSE NAME: Office 16, Office16SkypeforBusinessEntryR_PrepidBypass edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 16, RETAIL(Free) channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---LICENSED--- 
ERROR CODE: 0x4004FC05 (for information purposes only as the status is licensed)
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the application has a perpetual grace period.
Last 5 characters of installed product key: HT9YM
---------------------------------------
PRODUCT ID: 00198-20000-00000-AA054
SKU ID: ff693bf4-0276-4ddb-bb42-74ef1a0c9f4d
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeLyncEntryR_PrepidBypass edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, RETAIL(Free) channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---LICENSED--- 
ERROR CODE: 0x4004FC05 (for information purposes only as the status is licensed)
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the application has a perpetual grace period.
Last 5 characters of installed product key: BPW98
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---Exiting-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even thou I don't really like the way you try to solve this particular case, here is your code updated and hopefully providing expected results.

```
$comp = "Computername"
$OfficLice = "C:\share\OfficLice.csv"

$localtemp = cscript 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs' /dstatus $comp

$filteredOutput = $localtemp | Where-Object {($_ -like "License Name*") -or ($_ -like "Last 5*")}

$licenseInformation = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $filteredOutput.Count; $i = $i + 2) {
    $combinedLicenseInformation = [PSCustomObject]@{
      LicenseName = ($filteredOutput[$i] -split ' ')[4];
      Last5Characters = ($filteredOutput[$i + 1] -split ' ')[7]
    }
    $licenseInformation += $combinedLicenseInformation
}

$licenseInformation | Export-Csv -Path $OfficLice -NoTypeInformation
```

Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a streamlined solution that uses the **`switch` statement's ability to process an *array* of input objects with *regex matching*** (as a bonus, `switch` is also noticeably faster than a pipeline solution):

```
$comp = "Computername"
$OfficLice = "C:\share\OfficLice.csv"

& { 
  switch -regex (cscript 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs' /dstatus $comp) {
    '^LICENSE NAME: (.*)' { 
        # Create a new custom object, filled with just the license name
        # for now.
        $o = [pscustomobject] @{
            Lic = $Matches[1]
            Key = ''
        }
    }
    '^Last 5 characters of installed product key: (.*)' { 
        # Add the license key info...
        $o.Key = $Matches[1] 
        # ... and output the complete object
        $o
    }
  }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $OfficLice
```

<sup>Note that `Export-Csv` uses ASCII encoding by default; use the `-Encoding` parameter, if needed.</sup>

With your sample input, the resulting CSV file looks like this:

```
"Lic","Key"
"Office 16, Office16HomeBusinessR_Retail3 edition","7H67X"
"Office 16, Office16SkypeforBusinessEntryR_PrepidBypass edition","HT9YM"
"Office 15, OfficeLyncEntryR_PrepidBypass edition","BPW98"
```

- `switch -regex (...)` runs the external `cscript` command and processes each resulting output line individually.
- Due to `-regex`, the branch conditionals are interpreted as regular expressions.
- Similar to using the `-match` operator, what the regular expression actually *captured* is recorded in the automatic `$Matches` variable, whose entry with index `1` contains what the *1st* capture group inside the regex (`(...)`) captured - in our case, the license name and the license key, respectively.
- The 1st branch handler initializes each output object with the license name, and the 2nd one adds the license key information, after which the object is output.
- The overall output from the `switch` statement is the array of all output objects, whose elements are passed one by one through to `Export-Csv`.

  - Note that enclosing the `switch` statement in `& { ... }` - i.e., invocation via a *script block* - is necessary for being able to use it in a pipeline.